# How do I remove all user profiles from a shared computer except for the ones in a csv file and an array?

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, scripting, operating-system

This is the original script I wrote. PowerShell will not display any of the system profiles in the pre determined array, but it completely disregards the fact that any of the users exist within the csv file. When I run the script, it spits out users that exist within the csv file, but not any of the profiles that match the profiles I have listed in the array.

```
$ADUsers = Import-CSV -Path C:\users\username\Desktop\DiskSpaceCleanup.csv | Sort SamAccountName
$ExcludedProfiles = @('administrator','Public','default','DOMAIN\administrator','NetworkService','LocalService','systemprofile')


$OnHardDrive = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile  

$userstoremove = @()
foreach($user in $OnHardDrive){
    if(($ADUsers -notcontains $user.LocalPath.split('\')[-1]) -and ($ExcludedProfiles -notcontains $user.LocalPath.split('\')[-1])){
        $userstoremove += $user
    }
}

$userstoremove.LocalPath | Format-Table
```

I was expecting this code to output anyone who is not in the $ExcludedProfiles array and anyone that is not in the $ADUsers array.

What actually ends up happening is the users in the csv file and the user profiles are not excluded from the results and the users I specified in the $ExcludedProfiles array are.

Any advice on how to filter out the users in the csv file from the results?

Comment: `$ADUsers` -> `$ADUsers.SamAccountName`. Better to extract the property values only once, up front: `(Import-CSV -Path C:\users\username\Desktop\DiskSpaceCleanup.csv).SamAccountName | Sort-Object`

Answer (score 1):

This might be a more robust way of doing it by translating the [NTAccounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.ntaccount?view=netframework-4.8) to their corresponding [SID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.securityidentifier?view=net-7.0) and then comparing against the SID property of the objects returned from `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile`. I only changed `SystemProfile` to `System` from your current list to actually target `NT AUTHORITY\System`.

**Worth noting, this solution only works on English locale. Thanks to [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron) for pointing that out.**

```bash
[Collections.Generic.HashSet[Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]] $excludedSIDs = @(
    (Import-CSV -Path C:\users\username\Desktop\DiskSpaceCleanup.csv).SamAccountName    
    'Administrator'
    'Public'
    'Default'
    'DOMAIN\Administrator'
    'NetworkService'
    'LocalService'
    'System'
) | ForEach-Object {
    try {
        [Security.Principal.NTAccount]::new($_).
            Translate([Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
    }
    catch { }
}

$OnHardDrive = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object {
    $excludedSIDs.Add($_.SID)
}
$OnHardDrive.LocalPath
```

The following should work on any Windows Locale but includes and uses the [WellKnownSidsType Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.wellknownsidtype?view=netframework-4.6.2) to generate the list of SIDs to exclude. The only problem is, this includes more SIDs than what OP might be interested in excluding.

```bash
$domainSid = [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]::new($env:USERNAME).
    Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).
    AccountDomainSid

[Collections.Generic.HashSet[Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]] $excludedSIDs = @(
    (Import-CSV -Path C:\users\username\Desktop\DiskSpaceCleanup.csv).SamAccountName |
        ForEach-Object {
            try {
                [Security.Principal.NTAccount]::new($_).
                    Translate([Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
            }
            catch { }
        }

    [Enum]::GetValues([System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType]) |
        ForEach-Object {
            try {
                [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]::new($_, $domainSid)
            }
            catch { }
        }
)

$OnHardDrive = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object {
    $excludedSIDs.Add($_.SID)
}
$OnHardDrive.LocalPath
```

Comment: @iRon thanks for the upvote. thats a really good point. I didn't think about that one.

Comment: @iRon I added a disclaimer, no idea how to deal with this in a different locale. Never used other than English and never will. Thanks again for pointing it out, didnt even consider it before.

Comment: You could use a selection from the [Well-known SIDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/understand-security-identifiers#well-known-sids) to have this locale independent as these are universal on Windows operating systems.